# Finding records by ID with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ransack

I am working with a rails app that uses ransack. I currently have an error in one of the views. The error reads

> No valid predicate for course_id

Upon researching, the solution seems to be converting the id columns from integer to string. I saw this code online but i am confused as to which file to place the code in

```
  ransacker :id do
    Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(
    "regexp_replace(to_char(\"#{table_name}\".\"id\", '99999999'), ' 
    ', '', 'g')"
    )
  end
```

This is my ransack.rb file

```
ENV["RANSACK_FORM_BUILDER"] = "SimpleForm::FormBuilder"

require "ransack"
Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.ignore_unknown_conditions = false
end
```

in my erb file, i have

```
<%= simple_search_form_for @ransack do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.input :id_eq %>
      <%= f.input :title_cont %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ransacker: `Arel.sql("CONVERT(course.id, CHAR(7))")`.